# Custom aggregation with conditional cumsum

Tags: python, pandas, aggregation, cumsum

I have a dataframe which looks like this

[image]

Depending on the user action (four types of action are possible) I want to accumulate user's amount of money at the given point of time. Actions of type A and B represent user income, actions of type C and D represent user's expense.

In other words, I want to have something like this as a result

[image]

User 1 first performs action_A and get 10 as result. Then action_B gives us 10 + 5 = 15. Action_C represents money loss and gives use 15 - 5 = 10. Finally, action_D is the same as C and we get 10 - 15 = -5.

How can I implement this with pandas? I tried custom aggregation using

```
expanding().apply(agg_func)
```

but didn't get any satisfying result.

EDIT: code for dataframe creation

```
ids = [1,1,1,1,2,2]
dates = ['2019-03-07 13:54', '2019-03-07 16:07', '2019-03-10 19:20', '2019-03-10 19:20', '2016-03-07 14:47', '2016-03-09 11:07']
amounts = [10., 5., 5., 15., 2., 4.]
actions = ['action_A', 'action_B', 'action_C', 'action_D', 'action_A', 'action_B']
result = [10, 15, 10, -5, 2, 6]

pd.DataFrame({'user_id': ids, 'start_date': dates, 'amount': amounts, 'action': actions, 'result': result}, index=range(6))
```

Comment: You should always share your sample data in text.

Comment: @QuangHoang I added the code for dataframe creation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiple values by `-1` by mask created by [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) and [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) and last use [`GroupBy.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumsum.html):

```
df['result'] = (df['amount'].mask(df['action'].isin(['action_C','action_D']),
                                  df['amount'] * -1)
                           .groupby(df['user'])
                           .cumsum())
print (df['result'])
0    10.0
1    15.0
2    10.0
3    -5.0
4     2.0
5     6.0
Name: result, dtype: float64
```

Similar solution with helper column:

```
df['result'] = (df.assign(tmp = df['amount'].mask(df['action'].isin(['action_C','action_D']),
                                 df['amount']*-1))
                  .groupby('user')['tmp']
                  .cumsum())
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey hope this will give you a hint:

First I give negative sign to action that represent an expense.

```
df.loc[df.action.isin(['action_C','action_D'])].amount = -1 * df.loc[df.action.isin(['action_C','action_D'])].amount
```

then you create the result column like this

```
df['result'] = df.amount.cumsum()
```

Comment: Yeah just figure out there is a little mistake trying to fix it !

Comment: I don't think that checking the same thing twice is the most efficient. It is much more to use mask ...

Comment: yes I agree using  `mask` avoid the permanent modification of dataframe. Otherwise we can get back our initial dataframe by multypling another time by -1 but yes it's less efficient than using`mask` method.

Comment: You also need to use `groupby`. Note that the cumulative sum is restarted when switching users